# Insert line into an existing table in Microsoft Word 2007?

Tags: microsoft-word-2007, microsoft-word-2003

This is driving me nuts!

Is there a way to quickly insert a line to an existing Word 2007 table? In Word 2003 there was a specific button for this - it was quite easy to splice and dice existing cells in an existing table.

Answer (score 3):

[image]

There are several ways to do this:

- **A:** Place the cursor *just outside* the table, then press <kbd>ENTER</kbd>.
- **B:** Add buttons to the Quick Access Toolbar (and even assign keyboard short-cuts).
  The commands you need to add are called:

  - Insert Rows
  - Insert Rows Above
  - Insert Rows Below
- **C:** When the cursor is inside the table, click the "Layout" tab to reveal the buttons
- **D:** Right click inside the table, open the "Insert" sub-menu

Answer (score 2):

Highlight any row and right click to get the option to insert below or above the current line.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure this question is relevant, but if you click on the layout tab while your cursor is in the table, all those functions are there.  They are also in the rightclick menu.

Answer (score 0):

If you mean drawing a line to split a cell, you can still do this using Insert, Table, Draw Table. If this is an option you use a lot, you can add it to the Quick Access Toolbar from the right-click menu on the command.

Another tip, which might be relevant, is that when you are in the last cell of a table, pressing the Tab key will add another row.